# Accessing nodes from a single IP

Tags: node.js, networking, network-programming

I'm developing a web application through node.js that connects to different clients in the network through a single port. In the image below, the web application works on all PCs with IP addresses 10.0.9.*.

What would be the best way to include the nodes below (using IPs 192.168.11.*) that share the same IP addresses but have other local unique addresses?
[image: network infrastructure]

Or is there another solution to this problem? I may be boxed with the idea that they need to have unique 10.0.1.* addresses.

Comment: Either the clients should open the connection so that your router handles the connections, or you'll need to do port mapping on the router at 10.0.9.7 (and connect to multiple ports, each representing a unique client on the other network segment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to access the nodes in 10.0.9.7 using [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).
For example, your application can listen on a port from 6726-6730. All nodes will check these ports for each node they discover in the network.

Each open port will be treated as a node. Check the image below:

[image: Network architecture]